# Visual Studio debug shows good result but exe doesn't do what I need

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, directx-11

I'm studying DX11, and now have one strange problem. I'm generating bitmap `font(bmfont utilite)`and the program should render it.

When start Visual Studio debug everything is OK:

[image]

But when starting exe-file, nothing is rendered, but debug log says everything initialised correctly:

[image]

Log:

```
13:42:47::19: *DEBUG: Creating window
13:42:47::28: *DEBUG: initializing d3d
13:42:47::28: *DEBUG: client size 800 x 600
13:42:47::38: *DEBUG: driver type - 1 /1-hardware,2-reference,5-warp/
13:42:47::40: *DEBUG: render target view created
13:42:47::122: *DEBUG: font_0.tga texture loaded
13:42:47::123: *DEBUG: font_0.tga  - empty texture2d created
13:42:47::125: *DEBUG: font_0.tga  - texture2d data added
13:42:47::125: *DEBUG: font_0.tga  - shader resource view created
13:42:47::133: *DEBUG: font font.fnt shader created
13:42:47::135: *DEBUG: font font.fnt inited
13:42:47::136: *DEBUG: text created
13:42:47::137: *DEBUG: MyRender inited
13:47:17::269568: *DEBUG: font font_0.tga released
13:47:17::269570: *DEBUG: text released
13:47:17::269571: *DEBUG: releasing swap chain
13:47:17::269571: *DEBUG: releasing context
13:47:17::269574: *DEBUG: releasing device
13:47:17::269578: *DEBUG: Window Close
```

All files are in the correct directories, and I'm running Visual Studio 2015.

```
bool MyRender::Init()
{
    m_font = new BitmapFont(this);
    if (!m_font)
    {
        Log::Get()->Err("font not created");
        return false;
    }
    m_font->Init("font.fnt");

    m_text = new Text(this, m_font);
    if (!m_text)
    {
        Log::Get()->Err("text not created");
        return false;
    }
    m_text->Init(L"testing texting", true, 20);

    Log::Get()->Debug("MyRender inited");
    return true;
}

bool MyRender::Draw()
{
    TurnZBufferOff();
    TurnAlphaBlendingOn();

    m_text->Draw(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 50.0f, 2.0f);

    return true;
}
```

m_text->Draw(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 50.0f, 2.0f) : R,G,B color, X, Y position

Comment: Please edit your question to include a minimal, complete and virifiable example thatt shows your problem. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: It's probably because of path. When launching executable from debugger, current directory will be different but when you run the executable w/o debugger then current directory will point to the executable path

Comment: Unfortunately its not because of path. I checked if firstly, and log should print, if file is missing

Comment: Problem solved. I used different versions of bitmap font for debug and exe-file, but somehow it was the same names, stupid me)) Sorry for wasting your time